# asp.net mvc jquery razor check and uncheck checkbox in a group

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to check and unchecked the check boxes here in a group . i want to click the corresponding parent(id=50 , id=51) then all its child check boxes should be clicked. i am trying closest and find jquery functions with some alteration but couldn't make it work. how can i achieve check and uncheck in the following scenario

```
<tr id="50">
<td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="parent">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> paper1</b></td>
</tr>  

<tr id="173">
 <td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="child">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> sub1</b></td>
</tr> 

 <tr id="174">
 <td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="child">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> sub2</b></td>
 </tr>
```

this is group 2

```
 <tr id="51">
<td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="parent">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> paper2</b></td>
</tr>  

<tr id="175">
 <td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="child">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> sub1</b></td>
</tr> 

 <tr id="173">
 <td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="child">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> sub2</b></td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The value of ID must be unique within the HTML document**

Lets say the ID last tr is 176.

Please take a look at fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9qkjqLcj

```js
$("#50").click(function(){
  if($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked'))
    $("#173,#174").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
  else
    $("#173,#174").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
});

$("#51").click(function(){
  if($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked"))
    $("#175, #176").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
   else
    $("#175, #176").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="50">
<td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="parent">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> paper1</b></td>
</tr>  

<tr id="173">
 <td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="child">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> sub1</b></td>
</tr> 

 <tr id="174">
 <td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="child">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> sub2</b></td>
 </tr>
  <tr id="51">
<td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="parent">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> paper2</b></td>
</tr>  

<tr id="175">
 <td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="child">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> sub1</b></td>
</tr> 

 <tr id="176">
 <td colspan="2">
<b><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated" id="MediaPlanBoxes_0__isRoGenerated" class="child">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="MediaPlanBoxes[0].isRoGenerated"> sub2</b></td>
 </tr>
     </table>
```